# How to reference a css style sheet from a dynamically created webpage in a webbrowser control in c# wpf?

Tags: c#, css, wpf, hyperlink, browser

I create a Webpage dynamically and Show it with the NavigateToString method of the Webbrowser control. I'ld like to reference a style sheet like this:

```
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

I placed style.css in the applications workdir. But it doesn't work. When I save the created Website to a html file, place the style.css next to it and open that it in a browser, it displays corretly.

How can I reference static files like that?

Answer (score 0):

You Can do this:

Before navigate to html string Change It's Css address

```
string html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Your html file").Replace("BaseAdress", @"location of css file");
```

### Example:

**Html File:**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="BaseAdress\style.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>hi</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**CS Code:**

```
string html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"E:\1.html").Replace("BaseAdress",@"E:\");
webBrowser1.NavigateToSting(html);
```

Comment: Nah that's not the Problem. I don't just load the html file from disk. I create it dynamically in Memory. So I can directly put the path to my css file in the string while creating it. However, my Problem is, whatever I tried using as path to my css file, it didn't use it. I tried absolute path, relative path, as well as e:\... Notation as well as file:///e... Notation. It never uses the css file. Instead it Shows the Default - like when no css file is specified.